# Get difference between content data in 2 tables with same structure

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 SQLite tables (one of them temporary), and I need to know the difference in their content (old data vs. new data). I can use more than one query if needed and I will explain below:

```
Table structure:
- id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
- data TEXT NOT NULL
```

Let's suppose the old data is:

```
Table "olddata"

id - data
 1 - abc
 2 - def
 3 - ghi
 4 - jkl
```

And the new data (temporary table) is:

```
Table "newdata"

id - data
 1 - test
 3 - ghi
 5 - mno
 6 - pqr
```

What I need to know is:

```
1 was updated
2 was deleted
3 had no change
4 was deleted
5 was include
6 was include
```

I am new with SQL, specially SQLite. From my limited knowledge, the ideia is to do 3 different queries:

```
Get included records:
- Select all "ids" from newdata that are not in olddata

Get removed records:
- Select all "ids" from olddata that are not in newdata

Get updated records:
- Select all same "ids" from olddata AND newdata, with different data field content
```

I already researched and found some people using LEFT JOIN, other using EXCEPT, other using NOT IN... Please, can someone help me with this queries using the best approach?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the case for a `full join`. However, SQLite doesn't support it. So you have to do it with 3 queries.

```
--value changed or not
select o.id,case when o.val <> n.val then 'updated'
                 when o.val = n.val then 'no change'
            end as changetype
from olddata o
join newdata n on n.id=o.id
union all
--deleted records
select o.id,'deleted' as changetype
from olddata o
left join newdata n on n.id=o.id 
where n.id is null 
union all
--added records
select n.id,'added' as changetype
from newdata n
left join olddata o on n.id=o.id
where o.id is null
```

- Use inner join to compare values for any changes
- Left join on the old table to check for deletions
- Left join on the new table to check for new additions

Comment: Thank you and sorry about delay! I will try to understand the code and make tests ...

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple `Union All` and conditional aggregation would do the trick

```
Select ID
      ,max(case when Src=1 then ID else null end)   as Old_ID
      ,max(case when Src=2 then ID else null end)   as New_ID
      ,max(case when Src=1 then Data else null end) as Old_Data
      ,max(case when Src=2 then Data else null end) as New_Data
      ,case when count(*)=2 and min(data)=max(data) then 'No Change'  
            when count(*)=2 and min(data)<>max(data) then 'Updated'  
            when count(*)=1 and max(Src)=1 then 'Deleted'
            when count(*)=1 and max(Src)=2 then 'Added'
        else null end as Status
 From (
        Select 1 as Src,Old_ID as ID,Old_Data as Data From OldData
        Union All
        Select 2 as Src,New_ID as ID,New_Data as Data From NewData
      ) A       
 Group By A.ID
```

Comment: @Paruba Please do.  I'm sure it'll be OK. This approach is pretty straight forward.

Comment: I am trying your solution but the code is too complex for my limited knowledge. I think the bigger problem for my understanding is that I used the same fields name for both tables. Please, could you change your code using this tables: olddata (old_id, old_data) and newdata (new_id, new_data) for me to understand ? Thank you again!

Comment: Oh, and the "No Change" could be ignored... but I think I can handle it if you could help me only changing the fields name... Thanks!

Comment: Mr. Cappelletti, please, wich ID is the first "Select ID", old_id or new_id? And in the next 2 "CASE" lines, wich "data" are you refering? Thank you!

Comment: @Paruba It doesn't matter.  If updated or no change, both IDs exists in Old and New.  If Deleted it only exists in Old.  If Added it only exists in New.  In the sub-query, the data is normalized into Src,ID, and Data.  Src=1 for Old and Src=2 for New

Comment: Actually I need to select both "id" and "data" fields, when updated, deleted or added. I don't know when using old_data or new_data in the query...

Comment: @Paruba See update.  ,,, This was not the original question

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry! But I thought would be easier for people to understand the original question, and then I could change for my needs...

Answer (score 0):

Added IDs are those that do not appear in the old data:

```
SELECT id FROM newdata WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM olddata);
```

Deleted IDs are those that do not appear in the new data:

```
SELECT id FROM olddata WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM newdata);
```

Changed rows can be determined by taking all rows with IDs that exist in both tables, and then removing all identical rows with a [compound SELECT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound) statement:

```
SELECT * FROM newdata WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM olddata)
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM olddata;
```

If you wanted to get all unchanged rows, you could simply use intersection:

```
SELECT * FROM newdata
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM olddata;
```

(These queries work for any number of data columns.)

Comment: Sorry about delay, it is 7am here I just wake up... Thank you so much for helping me, I will analise you code ...